# keydb (redis) in cluster mode with bitmani

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, keydb

We are using a redis cluster in kubernetes with the bitnami helm. This is quite easy to maintain and works.(https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis-cluster/#installing-the-chart)

Now, we want to switch to keydb, which is a fork of redis. It supports all redis commands.
But the bitnami helm uses some bitnami docker image, is there a easy way to use the keydb docker image instead?